# Change row color in picker view

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Is there any way to change picker view object color in row?

For example you have `addobject:@"black"` but how to change font color in red?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the "title" delegate method, you use the UIView method, and you create and populate your own view. So you create a UIView of 320 wide by say 44 high, put a label in it, set the label text and color, and now you have exactly what you want.

EDIT:

```
#define PICKER_VIEW_SIZE CGSize(300, 40)

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return PICKER_VIEW_SIZE.height;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return PICKER_VIEW_SIZE.width;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    // assume one component, but this solutions works for multiple
    // lets do red, green, and blue alternating backgrounds with alternating black and white text

    UIColor *backgroundColor;
    switch(row % 3) {
    case 0:
    default:
        backgroundColor = [UICOlor redColor];
        break;
    case 1:
        backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 2:
        backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        break;
    }
    UIColor *textColor = (row % 2) ? [UIColor blackColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ {0,0}, PICKER_VIEW_SIZE}];
    view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

    UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 20)];
    // configure the label
    label.text = text appropriate for this row;

    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Yes i know for that method but i want that every line(row) have a different color. Is that even possible?

Comment: Sure its possible! When you are asked for a view for a row, you decide what color to make it. That delegate method is telling you what the column and row is. You can make each view different - use a different background color, font, text color, etc. You can do whatever you want!

Comment: Can you post some example, please?